# Carregar um Combobox com Valor Selecionado

Tags: laravel, selected-option

Eu preciso editar um cadastro de equipamentos que tem vários combos e quando clicar em editar carregar o `select` já com o `selected` selecionado.

Achei que o Laravel identificava automaticamente mas parece que não.

Eu carrego fazendo um `foreach` na view edit(form).
Como fazer isto ?

Comment: Você tem o pacote LaravelCollective instalado em seu projeto ?

Comment: Não. Nem conheço.

Comment: Coloca a view que gera o `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Seria legal você instalar o [Laravel Collective](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#installation).

Você vai ter acesso a classe `Form`.

Exemplo de `combobox` preenchido com dados do banco:

### Controller

```
$users = User::orderBy('nome')
->get()
->lists('nome', 'id');

return view('backend.cadastro')->with('users', $users');
```

### View

```
{!! Form::select('usuarios', $users, VALOR_SELECIONADO) !!}
```

**Parâmetros:**: `(NAME, ARRAY_DE_VALORES, VALUE DEFAULT, ARRAY)`

Aonde está escrito acima `VALOR_SELECIONADO` é onde você vai colocar o ID do valor que tem que vir selecionado no `combobox`. Daí você adapta ao seu caso.

Comment: O que é usuarios? A tabela?

Comment: Este combo que quero colocar já selecionado é um relacionamento. Eu tenho que fazer o relacionamento antes?

Comment: Ter que instalar uma dependência inteira para realizar uma função simples é dispensável e além disso vai consumir recursos no projeto. Tudo isso se resolveria com um `{!! $x == $value ? "selected" : "" !!}` no inline do foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Diferente de ter que usar um pacote para isso, poderá utilizar a variável que já vem pre-definida no Blade [`$loop`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable).

```php
<select id="usuario_selecionado">
    @foreach($usuarios as $usuario)
        <option selected="{{ $loop->first ? "selected" : "" }}">{{ $usuario->nome }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

No exemplo acima, o código irá verificar se `$loop->first` é `true`, e se for, definirá o estado `selected` como verdadeiro no elemento.

Você pode utilizar outras condições para selecionar automaticamente, como uma condicional para selecionar alguém em específico ou outros itens do select. Isso fica a seu critério.